# How to send URL data from HTML to a CSS variable?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm trying to integrate this card styling (https://codepen.io/simeydotme/pen/PrQKgo) into my rails app. But it seems quite difficult to do so because my code generates the image URL on the HTML, but this CodePen has its image URLS declared in the CSS inside a variable like `--charizardfront:`.

My qestion is, how can you modify this CodePen so that it works by taking the URLs from the HTML instead?

The CodePen and my project uses SCSS, so perhaps that give us more options?

This is my `_profile-quest_cards.html.erb` code for the card/s that I want to style if anyone is interested:

```
  <div class="profile-carousel profile-carousel--quest_cards">
    <div id="profile-carousel-quest_cards-actual">
      <% current_user.quest_cards.each do |quest_card| %>
        <div class="profile-carousel-item profile-carousel-item--quest_cards" data-asset-id="<%= quest_card.id %>">
          <div class="profile-carousel-award profile-carousel-award--quest_cards">
            <div class="award-image">
              <%= image_tag(quest_card.url) %>
            </div>
            <div class="award-meta">
              <span class="name"><%= quest_card.label %></span>
              <span class="for"><%= quest_card.description %></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="profile-carousel-quest_cards-arrow-left" class="profile-carousel-arrow profile-carousel-arrow--left profile-carousel-arrow--quest_cards">
    <div class="arrow-wrapper"><div class="arrow"><span class="cs-icon cs-arrow-down"></span></div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="profile-carousel-quest_cards-arrow-right" class="profile-carousel-arrow profile-carousel-arrow--right profile-carousel-arrow--quest_cards">
    <div class="arrow-wrapper"><div class="arrow"><span class="cs-icon cs-arrow-down"></span></div></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope I can accomplish my task without using JavaScript, but if that's the best solution then I'll take it.

Comment: What does that SCSS compile into, ie what is the resulting CSS?

Comment: @AHaworth It seems the resulting CSS on codepen is almost the same because the original SCSS code doesn't use that much SCSS based syntax or variables.

Comment: Instead of altering the CSS and instead of putting a data attribute in the HTML could you put a style attribute which sets the variable to the correct form?

Comment: @AHaworth that's a good idea, You mean like this? `<div class="card charizard animated" style="--charizardfront: url(https://assets.codepen.io/13471/charizard-gx.webp);"></div>` I tried that on codepen, and commented out the CSS code `--charizardfront: url(https://assets.codepen.io/13471/charizard-gx.webp);` It shows the image initially but it seems to disappear on mouse hover. Please take a look by editing the code on codepen. Thanks a lot for your tips 

Comment: @Alex seems to have sussed the problem, a question of scope as in the original variables are set much higher up e.g. at :root rather than locally.

Comment: You could simply add the attribute `style="background-image: url(https://assets.codepen.io/13471/charizard-gx.webp)"`, that would be the quickest solution. What is the need for you to have it in a css custom property?

Comment: @AmauryHanser the code on codepen uses some advanced CSS that I don't know how to manipulate unfortunately.. Do you know how to apply your suggestion and modify the CSS on codepen to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating solution from the comments to an answer:</sub>

> Because JavaScript overrides style attribute for fancy animations. Do this, instead:
>
> ```
> <div style="--charizardfront: url(https://assets.codepen.io/13471/charizard-gx.webp);">
>     <div class="card charizard animated"></div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> – [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207090/alex) - [Jan 17 at 6:31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142274/how-to-send-url-data-from-html-to-a-css-variable#comment132602190_75142274)

Answer (score -1):

HTML divs don't use urls as attributes. You're probably looking for

```
<img>
```

Try something like

```
<img src='path'></img>
```

Comment: Hmm I don't fully understand, are you able to edit it on the codepen link I posted so that the CSS uses the URL from the HTML to make the animation work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).